# How to display the value of 64¹⁵ in C?

Tags: c, variables, math, io

I want to assign the value of 64<sup>15</sup> to a variable and display it.

Note I don't want to display like this `1.2379400392853803e+27`. I  want to display all the digits.

Comment: `printf("%.0f\n", pow(64, 15));`?

Comment: `printf("%d\n",64^15);`?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage, `^` is xor bitwise in C ;)

Comment: @AlterMann I knew that :)

Comment: I know this but it will not help this will not display all the digits

Comment: @rock: https://ideone.com/hLxhPy

Comment: @rock Then how about `char *s="1237940039285380274899124224";`? I think what people are trying to tell you here is that C has no built-in data type that can store integers this large. (Except, perhaps, `uint128_t`, which is supported by some compilers but, AFAIK, cannot be assigned directly.)

Comment: @squeamishossifrage, 64^15 fits into a double

Comment: @AlterMann Yes, but `double` is not an integer type.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage: There is no mention to integer types in the OP question

Comment: "it will not help this will not display all the digits" --> It prints `1237940039285380274899124224' on my machine.  What did it print on yours?

Answer (score 3):

C/C++ does not have native support for integers that large. You'll have to resort to a third-party library for such functionality. For example: https://gmplib.org